# Why is the mean = 0 to calculate the confidence intervals of a distribution when using stats.norm?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

I somewhat understand how to calculate the Confidence interval in this manner but why is it that in this code, they used the mean=0 within the `stats.norm`

```
se = np.std(data) / np.sqrt(len(data))

sample_mean = data.mean()
difference_means_distribution = stats.norm(0 <<<<<, se)
lower, upper = (sample_mean + difference_means_distribution.ppf(0.025),
                sample_mean - difference_means_distribution.ppf(0.025))
```

Shouldn't it be `stats.norm(sample_mean, se)` ?

Comment: This doesn't look like valid Python... what is `<<<<<`? Did you add that?

Comment: Since you're estimating the standard error, you should be using Student's t distribution rather than the normal to construct confidence intervals or perform hypothesis tests. The t will converge to normality as d.f. -> infinity, and captures the additional variability of using an estimate since you don't know the true value of the variance.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I added that just to highlight where my doubt was

Comment: @pjs So I use t test whenever I dont know the varience? The reason why this is this way is because it was on an exercise assignment for confidence intervals

Comment: @PedroMeyer Not quite. You use the t-distribution when the underlying distribution is normal but the variance is unknown (and therefore estimated) and the estimates of the mean and variance are independent; or when the underlying distribution is not normal but the sample size is sufficiently large to invoke the central limit theorem and the ratio of the sample variance to the true variance follows a chi-squared distribution. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) for details.

Comment: William Sealy Gosset did quality control work for Guinness Brewery, and noted that the error rate was higher than predicted using Z-based testing of samples. He used Guinness’s “study leave” policy to do research into the cause of and solution to his problem at University College London in 1906-1907, and published results using the pseudonym Student (because Guinness didn’t want competitors to know their QC processes) in 1908.